# Trying to display nested div inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div made up of nested elements but am having trouble displaying it inline:

https://jsfiddle.net/Stref/bp5ze9pn/

```
#liverpool-circle {
    display: inline;
}
#kings-circle {
    display: inline;
}
#london-circle {
    display: inline;
}
#waterloo-circle {
    display: inline;
}
#padidngton-circle {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Try to use inline-block instead of inline https://jsfiddle.net/bp5ze9pn/1/

Comment: Define "trouble". What's happening and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: This: http://postimg.org/image/glavj70jn/ And I am about to throw the computer out the window...

Answer (score 1):

Just add one class like this so you don't have to repeat css line https://jsfiddle.net/bp5ze9pn/4/

HTML

```
<div id="liverpool-circle" class="circle">
    <a onclick="liverpool();">
        <div class="circle">
            <h3 class="numbers">3</h3>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="kings-circle" class="circle">
    <a onclick="kings();">
        <div class="circle">
            <h3 class="numbers">7</h3>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="london-circle" class="circle">
    <a onclick="london();">
        <div class="circle">
            <h3 class="numbers">8</h3>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="waterloo-circle" class="circle">
    <a onclick="waterloo();">
        <div class="circle">
            <h3 class="numbers">11</h3>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="paddington-circle" class="circle">
    <a onclick="paddington();">
        <div class="circle">
            <h3 class="numbers">18</h3>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
}
```